# how to generate list of records using list of lists data in erlang

Tags: erlang, logic

I have list of lists like
`ItemListData = [[1,"ABC","DEF",30],[2,"AXN","FOO",23],[3,"BDE","FO1",21],..]` and I would like to form list of records using record `Item{ItemNo, Name, Description, quantity}`. Items list length would be varying. What would be the best way to create new list of records using `ItemListData`.

Answer (score 1):

@graymalkin's answer involves a lot of copying through the use of the `++` binary operator.
One should prefer list comprehensions here:

```
make_records(Records) ->
    [#item{'#'=No, name=Name, descr=Descr, qty=Qty}
    || [No,Name,Descr,Qty] <- Records].
```

Edit:
Use this function thusly: (in the shell)

```
1> rd(item, {'#', name, descr, qty}).
2> ItemListData = [[1,"ABC","DEF",30],[2,"AXN","FOO",23],[3,"BDE","FO1",21]].
3> some_module:make_records(ItemListData).
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to call this function with following data                                                             ItemListData = [[1,"ABC","DEF",30],[2,"AXN","FOO",23],[3,"BDE","FO1",21],..] and record type Item{ItemNo, Name, Description, quantity} to get ItemsList[].

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do...

`make_records([], Records) -> Records;
make_records([[No,Name,Desc,Qty]|Xs], Records) ->
    make_records(Xs, Records ++ Item{itemNo = No, name = Name, desc = Desc, qty = Qty}).`

Answer (score 0):

You just need this:

```
rd(item, {num, name, descr, qty}).
L = [[1,"ABC","DEF",30],[2,"AXN","FOO",23],[3,"BDE","FO1",21]].
lists:map(fun([No, Name, Des, Qty]) -> #item{num = No, name=Name, descr=Des, qty=Qty} end, L).
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [list_to_tuple](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_tuple-1):

```
rd(item, {num, name, descr, qty}),    
Ls = [[1,"ABC","DEF",30],[2,"AXN","FOO",23],[3,"BDE","FO1",21]],
[list_to_tuple([item|L]) || L <- Ls].
```